# Mobile ARM processors for heavy 3d tasks?

Tags: cpu, arm

I would like to know, why ARM processors, like Snapdragon 855 aren't being used for heavy tasks like blender, CAD, etc. Because if we look at them, their specs aren't so bad. 8 cores @ 2.84 GHz. Not every desktop CPU have 8 cores. If we assume, that CAD or blender could be ported to the ARM architecture, what results maybe, if we run that same task on Snapdragon 855, and downclocked i7-9700k to Snapdragon's stock 2.54 GHz(And yeah. Without hyperthreading :D). Who would win and why?

Answer (score 1):

The [megahertz myth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megahertz_myth).

Number of cores and their clocks are not a reliable performance indicator. There's a lot of different factors that have impact on final performance. And mobile processors like Snapdragons are designed to be extremely power-efficient, not performant.

Snapdragon would probably be crushed even by i3 in rendering benchmarks.